# Getting error as '"Object(...) is not a function"' in console in Angular application

Tags: angular

I am writing a sample code for fetching the data from server using GET type of request,When I hit my application URL, i am getting no data on UI and an error in console.

```
private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';

getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
return this.http
  .get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
  .pipe(tap(_ => this.logMessage('Fetching heroes...')));
}
```

**Error image**

[image: error image]

Comment: Attach your full error log here so we can help you quickly

Comment: Is `this.logMessage` an `Object` or a `function`?

Comment: Please add some error logs and how the service is subscribed in your component.

Comment: That's a server error! It's your server that is saying that Object is not a function, not your front-end

Answer (score 0):

You needed to install rxjs

```
npm i rxjs@^6.0 rxjs-compat
```

import rxjs-compact into file

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs-compat';
import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operators';
```

[closed Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24804)

Comment: I am getting this error in Chrome console as : core.js:3688 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
core.js:1449 ERROR {body: {…}, url: "api/heroes", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}body: error: "Object(...) is not a function"__proto__: Objectheaders: HttpHeaderslazyInit: ƒ ()lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(0) {}__proto__: Objectstatus: 500statusText: "Internal Server Error"url: "api/heroes"__proto__: Object
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1449. Kindly go thru attached image in original question

Comment: That's a server erorr. What you are reading is the response of the `api/heroes` request

Comment: try following commands:
may it helpful for you

npm uninstall angular-in-memory-web-api --save

npm i angular-in-memory-web-api@0.8.0 --save

Comment: Tried this commands also, still the error is there. And the main thing is that my application is taking MOCK data from code, it is not taking the remote server data. That is the point of issue.

Comment: it looks like that the traces of the fake backend still there (if you used),So try to check carefully everything.

Comment: I commented them in code like : this.heroService
      .getHeroesWithHTTP()
      .subscribe(hers => (this.heroes = hers)); // this is from remote server
    // this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(hrs => (this.heroes = hrs)); // this is from MOCK data